# Hibernate One-to-One Mapping not fetching child class data with parent class

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-annotations

I have two tables, 1'st table contains company_id, company_name and country name and second table contain company related detail with one to one mapping.

This is my table structure :-

```
    company {
      company_id int,
      company_name varchar,
      country varchar
    }

    company_detail {
      id int,
      company_id int,
      company_description text,
      future_goal text
    }
```

Following mapping used in POJO :-

In Company POJO :-

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="COMPANY_ID")  
private CompanyDetails companyDetails;
```

In CompanyDetail POJO :-

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="COMPANY_ID")  
public Company company;
```

But when I get company object its contain null in companyDetails.

Following code used to get Company Object :-

```
  Company company = (Company) session.get(Company.class, companyId);
```

I want to get companyDetails data together with company data.

am I doing something wrong?
What Code changes required to fix this problem.

Comment: Your field is a private class of `CompanyCaptiveDetails` but your POJO is named `CompanyDetail`. Explain please

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected my question. Now Please Look

Comment: Read the hibernate documentation about bidirectional associations. one side (the one which doesn't have the foreign key) must be the inverse of the other side, using mappedBy. In your mapping, you define two separate one to one association. And you're telling that company.company_id is a join column (i.e. a foreign key) to company_detail.id, which is not true. I don't really see the point of these two tables. You could just put everything in the company table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the bidirectional `@OneToOne` relationships (read [more info](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne) about it):

```
// in Company POJO:
@OneToOne(mappedBy="company", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private CompanyDetails companyDetails

// in CompanyDetails POJO:
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="company_id")  
public Company company;
```

Then after fetching the `company` object, you can get it's details (as `Company` has `CompanyDetails` filed):

```
Company company = (Company) session.get(Company.class, companyId);
CompanyDetails details = company.getCompanyDetails();
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

In both POJOs you have:

```
@JoinColumn(name="COMPANY_ID")
```

You should change this to

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "company")
private CompanyDetails companyDetails;
```

and

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="COMPANY_ID")  
public Company company;
```

Comment: Thank you so much.